# why cin does not recognise plus/minus sign?

Tags: c++

```
char sign = '+';
cout << "Enter '+' for addition or '-' for subtraction: ";
        cin >> sign;
        if ( sign != '+' || sign != '-' ) {
            cout << "you can only enter '+' or '-'!\n";
            return 1;
        }
```

When I enter '+' or '-' sign, the error message will display.

Comment: Work the logic out more. Make a truth table with three possible values of `sign` or something.

Comment: and is the answer to most things

Comment: `(! (sign == '+' || sign == '-')) == (sign != '+' && sign != '-')`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: the answer is about math does not mean the question is about math. I though it was about cin that's why I asked the question...geez

Comment: Well, it's about boolean math, which is a subset of math. (j/k)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does. The problem with your code is this line:

```
    if ( sign != '+' || sign != '-' )
```

If `sign == '+'`, the first condition is false, but the second condition is true. Obviously `false || true` evaluates to `true`.

I think you mean to use `sign != '+' && sign != '-'`?

Answer (score 7):

There is an error in your truth table.  Consider the value `'+'`.  It is not equal to `'-'` hence the error prints.  The value `'-'` is not equal to `'+'` hence again the error prints.

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`

```
if ( sign != '+' && sign != '-' ) {
  ...
}
```